Error during user provisioning with sap ips
I have set up IPS for user provisioning from IAS to SAC. The target system is SAC. During user provisioning, I am encountering the following error:
system=TargetSAC

error=HTTP operation failed invoking https://host/api/v1/scim2/Users with statusCode: 400, Response: {"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],"status":"400","scimType":"invalidValue","detail":"Request is unparsable, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema. Wrong value of schemas attribute"},

content=<hidden content> - Set property ips.trace.failed.entity.content=true to display the content of failed entities

  

     {
        "user": {
            "condition": "($.emails[0].value EMPTY false) && isValidEmail($.emails[0].value)",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "targetPath": "$.schemas",
                    "constant": [
                        "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:user-custom-parameters",
                        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
                        "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "targetPath": "$.id",
                    "sourceVariable": "entityIdTargetSystem"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.emails[0].value",
                    "targetPath": "$.userName"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.emails[?(@.primary == true)].value",
                    "targetPath": "$.userName",
                    "condition": "$.emails[?(@.primary == true)].value != []",
                    "optional": true,
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": false
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.userName",
                    "targetPath": "$.userName",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.name.givenName",
                    "targetPath": "$.name.givenName",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.name.middleName",
                    "targetPath": "$.name.middleName",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.name.familyName",
                    "targetPath": "$.name.familyName",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.displayName",
                    "targetPath": "$.displayName",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.externalId",
                    "targetPath": "$.externalId",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.active",
                    "targetPath": "$.active",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.emails",
                    "targetPath": "$.emails",
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true
                },
                {
                    "targetPath": "$.emails[0].primary",
                    "condition": "$.emails[0].length() > 0",
                    "constant": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.groups[*].value",
                    "targetPath": "$.groups[?(@.value)]",
                    "optional": true,
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true,
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "resolveEntityIds",
                            "entityType": "group"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:user-custom-parameters']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:user-custom-parameters']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:user-custom-parameters']['idpUserId']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:user-custom-parameters']['idpUserId']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['manager']['value']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['manager']['value']",
                    "optional": true,
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "resolveEntityIds"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "group": {
            "condition": "('%sac.group.prefix%' === 'null') || ($.displayName =~ /%sac.group.prefix%.*/)",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "targetPath": "$.schemas",
                    "constant": [
                        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group",
                        "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-roles",
                        "urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.displayName",
                    "targetPath": "$.id",
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "replaceFirstString",
                            "condition": "('%sac.group.prefix%' !== 'null') && (@ =~ /%sac.group.prefix%.*/)",
                            "regex": "%sac.group.prefix%",
                            "replacement": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.displayName",
                    "targetPath": "$.displayName",
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "replaceFirstString",
                            "condition": "('%sac.group.prefix%' !== 'null') && (@ =~ /%sac.group.prefix%.*/)",
                            "regex": "%sac.group.prefix%",
                            "replacement": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.externalId",
                    "targetPath": "$.externalId",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.roles",
                    "targetPath": "$.roles",
                    "optional": true,
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.members[*].value",
                    "targetPath": "$.members[?(@.value)]",
                    "optional": true,
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true,
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "resolveEntityIds",
                            "entityType": "user"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-roles']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-roles']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:sap:cloud:scim:schemas:extension:custom:2.0:Group']['description']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:sap:params:scim:schemas:extension:sac:2.0:group-custom-parameters']['description']",
                    "optional": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }

Source System:

    {
        "user": {
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.id",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:sap:cloud:scim:schemas:extension:custom:2.0:User']['userId']",
                    "targetVariable": "entityIdSourceSystem"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['userId']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['userId']"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['userUuid']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['userUuid']"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.schemas",
                    "targetPath": "$.schemas",
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.userName",
                    "targetPath": "$.userName",
                    "optional": true,
                    "correlationAttribute": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.name.givenName",
                    "targetPath": "$.name.givenName",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.name.middleName",
                    "targetPath": "$.name.middleName",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.name.familyName",
                    "targetPath": "$.name.familyName",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.name.honorificPrefix",
                    "targetPath": "$.name.honorificPrefix",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.emails[*].value",
                    "targetPath": "$.emails[?(@.value)]",
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.emails[?(@.primary== true)].value",
                    "correlationAttribute": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.active",
                    "targetPath": "$.active"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.userType",
                    "targetPath": "$.userType",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.addresses",
                    "targetPath": "$.addresses",
                    "optional": true,
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.locale",
                    "targetPath": "$.locale",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.phoneNumbers",
                    "targetPath": "$.phoneNumbers",
                    "optional": true,
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.timezone",
                    "targetPath": "$.timezone",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.displayName",
                    "targetPath": "$.displayName",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.groups",
                    "targetPath": "$.groups",
                    "optional": true,
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true
                },
                {
                    "targetPath": "$.displayName",
                    "condition": "$.displayName EMPTY true",
                    "type": "remove"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['validFrom']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['validFrom']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['validTo']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['validTo']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['sourceSystem']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['sourceSystem']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['sourceSystemId']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:2.0:User']['sourceSystemId']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['employeeNumber']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['employeeNumber']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['costCenter']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['costCenter']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['organization']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['organization']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['division']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['division']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['department']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['department']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['manager']['value']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['manager']['value']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['manager']['displayName']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['manager']['displayName']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:sap:cloud:scim:schemas:extension:custom:2.0:User']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:sap:cloud:scim:schemas:extension:custom:2.0:User']",
                    "optional": true
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.company",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['organization']",
                    "optional": true
                }
            ]
        },
        "group": {
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.id",
                    "targetVariable": "entityIdSourceSystem"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$['urn:sap:cloud:scim:schemas:extension:custom:2.0:Group']['name']",
                    "targetPath": "$['urn:sap:cloud:scim:schemas:extension:custom:2.0:Group']['name']"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.displayName",
                    "targetPath": "$.displayName"
                },
                {
                    "sourcePath": "$.members",
                    "targetPath": "$.members",
                    "optional": true,
                    "preserveArrayWithSingleElement": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }

What could be causing this?

Hello All,  Could someone maybe give me a tip? Many Thanks
